# javascript div container width resize problem

Tags: javascript

hej guys,
I've got a problem trying to resize the width of a div container. I really don't know why it's not working...
Thx for responding.

here's the code: It really works with Google Chrome. But with IE or Firefox just won't work.

```
<div id="div1" style="position:relative; background-color:#000000; width:100px; height:20px; color:#ffffff; text-align:center;">
    <div id="div2" style="position:absolute; background-color:#00ff00; left:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px; width:10px; text-align:right;">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var container = document.getElementById("div1");
container.style.width = '300px';
</script>
```

Comment: Is this the whole of the code you have?  I just copied and pasted it into a HTML file and opened the file in Firefox, and it "works" for me.  I guess I'd like to know what "doesn't work" as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `document.getElementById()` comes to early. Your element is not available at the DOM. Maybe Chrome adds the elements faster (?).

You should not rely on the position of your scripts in the source code. Use a `onload()` handler instead.

Replace the content of the script-tag with the following and it should work.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var container = document.getElementById("div1");
    container.style.height = '100px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it all inside a body tag for the javascript to work (document.getElementById):

```
<body>

<div id="div1" style="position:relative; display:block; background-color:#000000; width:100px; height:20px; color:#ffffff; text-align:center;">
    <div id="div2" style="position:absolute; background-color:#00ff00; left:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px; width:10px; text-align:right;">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var container = document.getElementById("div1");
container.style.width = '300px';
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

@hacksteak25 has the answer, but if you want to attach handlers to the `load` events (or most other events) for anything more than a quick hack, you should use the DOM/IE APIs to add event handlers:

```
function() init{
    var container = document.getElementById("div1");
    container.style.height = '300px';
}

if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", init);
```